# electron electron-winstaller and squirell : how make and use an update.exe?

Tags: electron, installation, squirrel.windows

Thanks to windows electron-winstaller, I have created an installer for an application built with Electron Framework

I have followed this [tutorial](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/365/how-to-create-a-windows-installer-for-an-application-built-with-electron-framework) step by step that use squirrel

Unfortunately it does not explain how make an update.exe and where place it and how to use it

Could you help me to make an updater.exe that i could use locally fo exemple?

Comment: Hi there, are you planning to add auto updates to your app? Or are you planning to use the `update.exe` file for something else?

Comment: hi @Mike , I plan to make auto update in my app